# Proving $a^{2+n}a^{n}$ is regular using the Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

So I'm trying to practice (and learn, clearly) use of the Pumping Lemma, and this is my current equation. It's clearly regular- it can be simplified:

$a^{2+n}a^{n} = a^{2+2n}$ and from there it's fairly easy to derive the regular language $aa(aa)*$

However, I'm trying to explicitly solve this through the Pumping Lemma- but clearly doing something wrong. This is my process (assuming language $A$, string $s$ in $A$, pumping length $p$):

First take $s = aaaa$ for $n = 1$ (simple case).

Take $p = 2$, and so $xy$ must equal $aa$ to fit $|xy| \leq p$ and $|y| \gt 0$ , giving $x = a, y = a, z = aa$.

Finally insert into the equation $xy^{i}z \in A$ with a trivial value of $i \geq 1$ - $xy^{2}z$. This gives a result of $aaaaa$.

And that's the problem. $aaaaa$ is not a member of the language  $a^{2+n}a^{n}$. Is there a step I'm missing here or a wrong assumption?

Thanks. And apologies for yet another pumping-lemma question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>**Noooooo!**</sup>

Usage of the pumping lemma to prove regularity is remarkably rare, and certainly won't happen with a direct application.

Let's review the formal statement, with particular emphasis on the quantifiers:

$$\forall \ L \subseteq \Sigma^* ( \ L \ \text{is regular} \Rightarrow  \exists \ p \ge 1 \ \ \forall \ w \dots \ \ \exists \ x, y, z \dots \ \ \forall \ i \dots \ )$$

Two notable observations are that *being regular is part of the hypotheses* and that *nothing is said about the converse, which is in fact false* (a number of classical counterexamples can be found in literature).

In other words, even if you managed to somehow prove the $\exists \forall \exists \forall$ block, it still wouldn't say anything about the regularity of $L$. The way the pumping lemma is normally used is in its *contrapositive* form. You may recall from basic logic that $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (\neg q \rightarrow \neg p)$. Using that principle, we can derive the following logical consequence:

$$\forall \ L \subseteq \Sigma^* ( \ \forall \ p \ge 1 \ \ \exists \ w \dots \ \ \forall \ x, y, z \dots \ \ \exists \ i \dots \Rightarrow L \ \text{is }\textbf{not }\text{regular} \ )$$

Notice how this is a tool to prove *non-regularity*, and that, even there, nothing can be said about the converse.

I'm afraid your attempt of proof is just entirely misguided.

Comment: D'oh! I've just had a look back over some lecture notes and found that much has been said. That said, we've only been told that regular languages can be "[checked] using a DFA or NFA" or trivially in cases such as above- is there a better way? Thanks again

Comment: @Overt_Agent You're welcome! Proving things is inherently non-algorithmic, there is no one way. Generally, to prove regularity you do one of the following: (a) show a/an ($\epsilon$)-[D|N]FA, (b) write a regular expression for the language, or (c) use the closure properties of the set of regular languages. Generally, regular languages are nice enough that one of the above will single-handedly complete the proof. If that's not the case, you'll have to come up with an idea of your own.